# Problema al añadir Spring Security a mi aplicación

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

estoy teniendo problemas al intentar añadir las dependencias de Spring Securiy en mi fichero .pom Ahora mismo funcionando perfectamente (sin Spring Security) lo tengo asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.miproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>backendninja</name>
    <description>Mi proyecto</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Al añadir las dependencias de Spring Security se me queda tal que así:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.miproject</groupId>
<artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>backendninja</name>
<description>Mi proyecto</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Al añadirlo, me aparece el icono de error en el cuadro de la izquierda justo en el pom.xml y si pruebo a hacer un clean install me aparece el siguiente error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.502 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-06T19:29:50+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project backend: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.miproject:backend:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE from/to central_mirror 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project backendninja: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.miproject:backend:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
.....
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando y cómo solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Comment: Borra la carpeta repository dentro de la carpeta de .m2 (por defecto se encuentra en tus carpetas de usuario de windows) y entonces usa `Update Project Maven`.

Comment: No es necesario añadir SOLUCIONADO al título de tu pregunta, solo basta con marcar una respuesta como correcta como lo has hecho, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe de borrar la carpeta `repository` dentro de la carpeta `.m2`, esta carpeta por defecto se encuentra en la carpeta del usuario de Windows; tras realizar eso, vas a tu proyecto y pinchando con el botón derecho del ratón sobre el, usa la opción `Update Project Maven`.

Con esto consigues que se descarguen de nuevo todas las dependencias, en ciertas ocasiones al realizar la actualización de las dependencias en el `pom.xml` es posible que no se actualicen en la carpeta del repositorio de estas por lo que esta es una forma de forzar su descarga.

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)